# Insert tag after first occurrence of a <table>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-dark"><thead>
</thead></table>`
```

There are other `<table>` tags on the HTML page. I want it so that I can insert another `<table>` element after the above `<table>` occurrence. I've tried using `BeautifulSoup` to find the first table  with:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(filedata, 'html.parser')
        first_table = soup.find_all("table")[0]
    dashboard_result = dashboard.run()
    filedata = filedata.replace(first_table, '</table>' + dashboard_result)
```

The current "solution" will overwrite and not include anything that is not matched by the .replace method - i.e. filedata will not include anything else in the html page. If I just use a generic `.replace("</table>", dashboard_result)` it will overwrite all the `</table>` tag.

Comment: `.replace("</table>", dashboard_result, 1)` will replace only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the [`insert_after()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) method.

Also, since you only want the *first* table tag, use [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) instead of `find_all()[0]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<table class="table table-dark"><thead>
</thead></table>`"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.find("table").insert_after(soup.new_tag('NEW TABLE'))    

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<table class="table table-dark">
 <thead>
 </thead>
</table>
<NEW TABLE>
</NEW TABLE>
```

Comment: Insert after will also be in the table tag right? I want it so that the inserted tag is a newly opened tag and not enclosed in the soup.find found tag

Comment: @Bryan It will insert it after, see my edit with adding a new `table` tag